# Вывести задачи по дате, если эта дата есть в промежутке старта и дедлайна задачи

Tags: php, mysql

Как мне из базы вывести все задачи, в которых между промежутком старта и дедлайна, есть текущая дата?

Запутался как сделать:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tasck WHERE (datetime BETWEEN '$datestart 00:00:00' and '$dateend 23:59:59') ORDER BY datetime");
```

этот код выводит все данные в промежутке между датой старта и начала текущего дня, а мне надо чтобы выводило как описано в вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю ваших имен полей, но как-то так:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tasks`
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN `start_date` AND `end_date`
ORDER BY `start_date`
```

Запрос будет **верным**, но возможно неоптимальным, т.к. MySQL может не суметь подобрать индекс. 
Если EXPLAIN покажет полный перебор, можно индексируемую колонку вынести в левую часть неравенства.

```
… WHERE `start_date` <= NOW() AND `end_date` >= NOW()
```

MySQL гарантирует, что NOW() не сумеет измениться в пределах одного запроса. :)

Comment: это я понимаю, но у меня список дней месяца, как мне в таком случае сделать? дата месяца указана в формате 2016-03-08, а в базе start_date и end_date в формате datatime

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev, не понял! У вас часть полей строкового типа? Любые date, datetime и timestamp абсолютно прозрачно сравниваются между собой. Литералы вида 'YYYY-MM-DD' в тексте запроса при необходимости трактуются как дата.

Comment: все отлично, вы правильно ответили на вопрос. Я чет тупанул сам мог сделать =)